# Android ItemTouchHelper: How to draw growing circle during Swipe

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, itemtouchhelper

I am using an `ItemTouchHelper` to trigger a swipe action for a RecylcerView item. When swiping, a circle should appear in the background from the halfway point and this should get bigger and bigger until the complete item becomes the colour of the circle.

The result should look something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Currently I'm using the `onChildDraw` method of the `ItemTouchHelper`

```kotlin
override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas,recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {

...

val backgroundGrey = ColorDrawable()
backgroundGrey.Color.parseColor("#CFD8DC")
backgroundGrey.setBounds(
    itemView.right + dx,
    itemView.top,
    itemView.right,
    itemView.bottom
)
backgroundGrey.draw(c)

val itemHeight = itemView.bottom - itemView.top
val iconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - icon.intrinsicHeight) / 2
val iconMargin = (itemHeight - icon.intrinsicHeight) * 2
val iconLeft = itemView.right + iconMargin - icon.intrinsicWidth + dx
val iconRight = itemView.right + iconMargin + dx
val iconBottom = iconTop + icon.intrinsicHeight

val circle = GradientDrawable()
circle.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
circle.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
circle.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ba000d"))

cirle.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom) // Size like Icon
//cirle.setBounds(itemView.right + dx, itemView.top, itemView.right,itemView.bottom) // circle gets stretched
//cirle.setBounds(0, 0, 1500,1500) // circle overlaps other recyclerview items
cirle.draw(c)

val icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_baseline_delete_24)
icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom)
icon.draw(c)

}
```

I have tried different approaches, but none has brought the desired result.
The various results look like this:

[image]

or

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve the result from the top images?

Comment: What is your minimum API level? This might be solvable with `android:elevation` but it requires API 21.

Comment: In this example I use API level 28, which element then needs the `android:elevation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to put a clip on your canvas before drawing the circle as described e.g. in
[here](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-5-advanced-graphics-and-views/lesson-11-canvas/11-1c-p-apply-clipping-to-a-canvas/11-1c-p-apply-clipping-to-a-canvas.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed